# Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child. However component has only one child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik

[image: Console Error Pg 2][image: Console Error Pg 1]I am getting this error 'Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.' and chrome console says error is at "Formik" component. However my Formik component is only returning one child component. Below is my code can anybody tell me what is going wrong in it?

```
const Signup = () => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    const mutation = useMutation(Registration);
    return (
        <>
            <NavigationBar />
            <div className="jumbotron">
                <h3>Registration</h3>
            </div>
            <Container>
                <Formik initialValues={initialValues} validationSchema={SignupSchema} onSubmit={(values) => mutation.mutate(values)}> {
                    props => (
                        <Form>
                        <div className="d-flex flex-column">
                            <label className="mt-3 formLabel">First Name</label>
                            <Field name='FirstName' className="inputField" />
                            <div className="errorMessage"><ErrorMessage name='FirstName' /></div>
                            <label className="mt-3 formLabel">Last Name</label>
                            <Field name='LastName' className="inputField" />
                            <div className="errorMessage"><ErrorMessage name='LastName' className="errorMessage" /></div>
                            <label className="mt-3 formLabel">Email</label>
                            <Field name='Email' className="inputField" />
                            <div className="errorMessage"><ErrorMessage name='Email' className="errorMessage" /></div>
                            <label className="mt-3 formLabel">Brand Name</label>
                            <Field name='BrandName' className="inputField" />
                            <div className="errorMessage"><ErrorMessage name='BrandName' className="errorMessage" /></div>
                            <label className="mt-3 formLabel">Password</label>
                            <Field name='Password' type="password" className="inputField" />
                            <div className="errorMessage"><ErrorMessage name='Password' className="errorMessage" /></div>
                            <label className="mt-3 formLabel">Confirm Password</label>
                            <Field name='ConfirmPassword' type="password" className="inputField" />
                            <div className="errorMessage"><ErrorMessage name='ConfirmPassword' className="errorMessage" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <Button type="submit" variant="primary" className="mt-5 mr-3" style={{ float: 'right' }}>
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                        {mutation.isLoading ? <><br /><CircularProgress /></> : null}
                        {mutation.isError ? props.handleReset : null}
                        {mutation.isError ? <><br /><div className="errorMessage">{mutation.error.response.data}</div></> : null}
                    </Form>
                    )
                }

                </Formik>
            </Container>
        </>
    )
}

export default Signup;
```

Comment: Please show the entire stack trace

Comment: Can you copy/paste the error that is shown in the console?

Comment: Console Error Screen Shots have been added in my post